# Build image with data coordinates to pixel coordinates

Tags: c++, linux, image, pixel

I'm developing an algorithm in which the data points "navigate" in a 2D space

For developing and debugging purposes, I need to visualize such data in a way that I can identify the data points iterating in the image: whether they are behaving correctly at the borders of the 2D space or when interacting with one another.  Previously, I used ncurses for this, but it has some limitations.
Later on, I'll need to colorize some points according to some rules.

So, I was thinking of building an image where every point would correspond to a pixel coordinate.  The images should be built in background for later inspection. For the first debugging phase, with only 20 points, the images would be very small but I could zoom in them to see the points.  Later on, with more point, I could watch the collective behavior of them.

How can I achieve this in a **simple** manner?  Is there a way to it directly from my code a few lines of simple code or do I really have to use some graph library?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but after reading this I'm not sure what you want. Is it "I have a list of 2D coordinates and want to turn them into points on a white background"?

Comment: @us2012: I'm thinking on that, yes. And afterwards colorize some points/pixels.  But I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: Okay. You can do that without libraries by writing PPM files, but that's inefficient and contrived. Why do you not want to use some simple graphics/image library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a R&D effort, I would suggest looking at the Processing language, which makes experimental graphics easy.  http://processing.org/

Here is an example that plots coordinates as dots. I think this is what you would start with:

http://processing.org/examples/pointillism.html

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I didn't know about Processing.  At this point of development I've to continue developing with C++, though. There's no other answer, I'll accept yours as valid.